# How To write an SQL query to return all "historical records" for TODAY'S DATE (month and day) for EVERY YEAR in the DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I've been using Visual Studio, C#, and SQL Server for 8 months now and have created a very functional personal project as I've been learning.  But, there one bit of functionality I want in my program that I cannot get to work--automatically, that is.

If I type THIS into the button click event, run the program, and click the History button, it works perfectly.  All seven columns of information go to the datagridview perfectly.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AllConcertList WHERE Date LIKE '%%%%-05-27' ORDER BY DATE DESC; ", conn);
```

However, what is not awesome is that I want to write the query so that I can push a button ("History") that will return information from MAY 27 (or whatever today's date actually is) of EVERY YEAR, and I just can't figure out how to do it.  It is a "Happened On This Day In History" list.

Obviously, I need to keep `SELECT * FROM AllConcertList WHERE Date`...  Somehow I need to include GETDATE() otherwise how would the program know  to start with 05-27?  But then I feel I need to include DATEFROMPARTS because I only really want Month and Day to be static to whatever the actual date (today) is.  It must be a subquery in there somehow.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Something smells here. What is the datatype of the column (poorly named) Date? It seems like varchar since your query would fail due to a conversion error if it were something different. And if that is the case, then you should really REALLY reconsider that decision.

Comment: Hello.  No, it's not varchar.  The datatype is "date".  Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use with simple month() and day() functions based on whatever the system's GETDATE() value is.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
select 
      ACL.* 
   from 
      AllConcertList ACL
   where 
          month( ACL.Date ) = month( getdate()) 
      and day( ACL.Date ) = day( getdate())
   order by
      ACL.Date desc
```

No Parameters, no sql-injection

Comment: There is no textbox for injection to occur.  All this is is a button that, when clicked, pulls information directly from the db and throws it all into a datagrid.  But, I will absolutely plug your suggestions in and try them.  Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You can dynamically get today's month and date, then build your query string.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
String sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM AllConcertList WHERE Date LIKE '%%%%-{0}' ORDER BY DATE DESC;", today.ToString("MM-dd"));
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
```

And to show best practice, the same query, but parameterized.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
SqlCommand cmd =  new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AllConcertList WHERE Date LIKE @monthDate ORDER BY DATE DESC;", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDate", "%%%%-" + today.ToString("MM-dd"));
```

Comment: But please use a [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8) not a dynamically built string.

Comment: That will likely not work for all date formats (e.g. YDM).

Comment: Dale Burrell, the question mentioned this was for a personal project. There is no advantage to using a SqlParameter since the "parameter" is not retrieved from user input, because it's always known.

Comment: @zwbetz That kind of thinking is what makes SQL injection so prevalent. You should **almost never** do it this way (without parameters). If there is a strong reason to, then consider it. **But there is no strong reason here**. Show the OP (who is clearly a beginner, and thus likely keen to learn) the right, safe way to do it. _That is putting aside the issue that this solution won't reliably work, but that is a different issue - my earlier comment addresses that._

Comment: But SO is about best practices, not the worst imaginable practices

Comment: @mjwills Answer has been updated to include parameterized query. As for your comment on this not working for all date formats, would you expand on what you mean?

Comment: @mjwills I see. If OP is using a different date format than what was posted in the example query (ymd), then agreed, OP will need to tweak the code to the given date format.

Comment: As I said before, this project was started to get me learning c#, Visual Studio, and SQL Server 8 months ago.  Yes, I'm a noob.  But, I have learned a lot in 8 months.  One of the things I've learned over that time is that noobs should not follow the teachings of most of the tutorials on YouTube.  But, how will you know unless you go through all of them and then, eventually, come across folks to teach the 'correct way to do it'?  Regarding SQL Injection--all this is, is clicking a button and data is pulled into a datagrid.  That data cannot be manipulated.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, all projects that I have been working on since have included stored procedures and parameterized queries.  But, for THIS project...one that nobody will ever touch but me... the simple 'select * from' query is the most simple.  In fact, zwbetz nailed it.  I put that code in and bam... worked first time.  If you had any idea how many hours I've puzzled over this.

Comment: My NEXT task is to analyze that code and find out WHY it works.  It looks as though I was ALMOST there...  But, THANK YOU ZWBETZ!!!  And thank you for all of the other comments and the reminders for BEST PRACTICES.  I've been following Tim Corey and Wise Owl Tutorial videos.  So, I've learned how NOT to do it, but I'm also learning how to do things correctly.  :)